# Удалить всё от начала до второго встретившегося символа в верхнем регистре, перед которым должен быть пробел

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Исходный текст:

```
Капельная кофеварка Melitta Aroma Elegance DeLuxe
```

Должно получится:

```
Melitta Aroma Elegance DeLuxe
```

Пробовал такой регуляркой заменять на пустоту:
`^((?:.*?[А-ЯA-Z]){2})`

Но удаляет и вхождение, т.е. получается:

```
elitta Aroma Elegance DeLuxe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
^[А-ЯЁA-Z].*?\s(?=[А-ЯЁA-Z])
```

Если есть поддержка символьных классов Юникода, можно заменить `[А-ЯЁA-Z]` на `\p{Lu}`:

```
^\p{Lu}.*?\s(?=\p{Lu})
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/17mHdm/2).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[А-ЯЁA-Z]` - буква в верхнем регистре
- `.*?` - ноль и более символов, отличных от символа перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `\s` - пробел
- `(?=[А-ЯЁA-Z])` - сразу после текущей позиции должна быть буква в верхнем регистре.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает а как сделать что бы учитывало "пробел" перед буквой в верхнем регистре? на случай **КАПЕЛЬНАЯ кофеварка Melitta Aroma Elegance DeLuxe** -> **Melitta Aroma Elegance DeLuxe**

Comment: @АлексейСердюк Я обновил ответ.